# Are coroutines in Lua actually multithreaded?

Tags: multithreading, lua, coroutine

Lua coroutines provide cooperative multithreading, and there can only be one coroutine running at a time. So, how are they even different from a normal block of code (keeping aside  cases where there is a wait time specified in the code)? Also, do coroutines actually run on different threads?

Comment: `there can only be one coroutine running at a time` - Yes. `do coroutines actually run on different threads?` - No. `how are they even different from a normal block of code?` - Each coroutine has its own stack

Comment: please refer to the Lua reference manual. Programming in Lua also covers coroutines in depth. do not confuse Lua threads with system threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how are they even different from a normal block of code (keeping aside cases where there is a wait time specified in the code)?

Because when you return from the middle of a normal function, you can't later just jump back to where you were.

> Also, do coroutines actually run on different threads?

No. Only one is running at a time.